# Как изменить цвет, размер сектора круга при наведении на него?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Есть статичная круговая диаграмма.

Задача при наведении на сектор,

- вызвать callback функцию
- поменять размер сектора
- цвет
- а еще если можно выполнить дополнительную обводку по периметру окружности  пример на картинке

но последний пункт, если это слишком трудно, и костылем решить смогу (если получится справиться с первыми двумя пунктами), наложив одну диаграмму на другую.

Html структуру менять можно, главное получить результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var lastend = 0;
var data = [200, 60, 15]; //мои сектора
var myTotal = 0; 
var myColor = ['red', 'green', 'blue']; //цвета

for (var e = 0; e < data.length; e++) {
  myTotal += data[e];
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  // параметры: x, y, радиус, начальный угол, конечный угол, antiClockwise (boolean)
  ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, canvas.height / 2, lastend, lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / myTotal)), false);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.fill();
  lastend += Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / myTotal);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="200" height="200" />
```

Comment: еще актуально?), тут подойдет все тот же пикинг, как в этом ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/988105/188366

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю такой способ, считаем дистанцию от мышки до центра круга. 
Если дистанция меньше радиуса - мы навели на какой-то сектор, а на какой конкретно определяем по углу направления в сторону курсора мышки относительно центра круга.

```js
let data = [200, 60, 15]; 
let colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
let radius = canvas.height / 2 - 10;
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let total = data.reduce((a, b) => a + b); 
let radiuses = [radius, radius, radius];
let activeAngle, activeIndex;

function callback(active) {
  stat.textContent =  colors[active] || 'none';
  canvas.style.cursor = active > -1 ? 'pointer' : 'default';
}

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  let currentActiveIndex;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var lastend = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    let endAngle = lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / total));
    let isActive = activeAngle && activeAngle > lastend && activeAngle < endAngle;
    currentActiveIndex = isActive ? i : currentActiveIndex;
    radiuses[i] += isActive ? 1 : -1;
    radiuses[i] = Math.min(Math.max(radius, radiuses[i]), radius+10);
    ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, radiuses[i], lastend, endAngle);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.fill();
    lastend += Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / total);
  }
  activeIndex != currentActiveIndex && callback(activeIndex = currentActiveIndex);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render)

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let dy = e.layerY - canvas.height / 2;
  let dx = e.layerX - canvas.width / 2;
  let d = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) < radius;
  let a = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  activeAngle = d ? a < 0 ? a + 2*Math.PI : a : null;
})
```

```html
<span id="stat" style="position:absolute">none</span>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="175"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать для таких целей Pixi или любую другую библиотеку для работы с canvas. Ибо canvas api не имеет поддержки событий наведения или впринципе хранить какие-либо структурированные данные об отрисованных объектах. Для добавления подобных функций нужно писать обертки, которые будут хранить контекст  и кастомные характеристики, а судя по твоему коду - тебе не до этого. А вот в Pixi все уже есть, fabric.js тоже отлично подойдет для этой цели.

PS
на будущее имей в виду, что canvas рендерит только один кадр, если ты видишь взаимодействие с ним и какие-либо анимации (например анимация увеличения размера участка твоего графика), то они реализованы через нативные события и таймеры. на каждую 1/60 (60 кадров в сек.) canvas рендерится заново с новыми входными параметрами для абстрактных объектов.

Comment: Не совсем понял про обертки и кастомные характеристики)  мне до этого, главное решить задачу))  конечно чем красивее тем лучше, но для начала понять бы как. Посмотрю библиотеки, согласен и на такое решение)

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Pipe {
    constructor(_parent) {
        this.canvas = Pipe.genCanvasElement();
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.curent = null;
        this.mousemove = Pipe.debounce(this, function (_e) {
            // console.dir(_e)
            let xM, yM;
            xM = _e.offsetX;
            yM = _e.offsetY;
            let x, y;
            x = this.canvas.width / 2;
            y = this.canvas.height / 2;
            let radians = Math.atan2(yM - y, xM - x);
            let degrees = radians * 180 / Math.PI;
            if ((360 + degrees) < 360) {
                degrees = 360 + degrees;
                radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
            }
            // console.log(`x:${xM} y:${yM} radians:${radians} degrees:${degrees}`)
            // --
            this.curent = radians;
            // console.log('mousemove')
            this.render();
        }, 500);
        this.mouseleave = Pipe.debounce(this, function (_e) {
            this.curent = null;
            // console.log('mouseleave')
            if (Pipe.t)
                clearTimeout(Pipe.t);
            this.render();
        }, 500);
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mousemove);
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseleave);
        _parent.appendChild(this.canvas);
        this.render();
    }
    static debounce(self, f, ms) {
        return function (...args) {
            const onComplete = () => {
                f.apply(self, args);
                Pipe.t = null;
            };
            if (Pipe.t)
                clearTimeout(Pipe.t);
            Pipe.t = setTimeout(onComplete, ms);
        };
    }
    static genCanvasElement() {
        let c = document.createElement('canvas');
        c.width = 200;
        c.height = 200;
        c.style.border = 'solid grey 1px';
        return c;
    }
    static foo(ctx, fillStyle, x, y, r, startAngle, endAngle) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        ctx.arc(x, y, r, startAngle, endAngle, false);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    static foo2(startAngle, curent, endAngle, fillStyle, x, y, r, j, ctx) {
        // console.log(`
        //     startAngle:${startAngle}
        //     endAngle:${endAngle}
        //     this.curent:${this.curent}
        // `)
        if ((startAngle < curent) && (curent < endAngle)) {
            fillStyle = 'aqua';
            Pipe.foo(ctx, fillStyle, x, y, r + j, startAngle, endAngle);
        }
        else {
            Pipe.foo(ctx, fillStyle, x, y, r, startAngle, endAngle);
        }
    }
    render() {
        let ctx = this.ctx;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        let lastend = 0;
        let data = [200, 60, 15]; //мои сектора
        let myColor = ['red', 'green', 'blue']; //цвета
        let j = this.canvas.width / 8;
        let x, y, r;
        x = this.canvas.width / 2;
        y = this.canvas.height / 2;
        r = y - j;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let startAngle = lastend;
            let endAngle = lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / 360));
            let fillStyle = myColor[i];
            Pipe.foo2(startAngle, this.curent, endAngle, fillStyle, x, y, r, j, ctx);
            // --
            lastend += Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / 360);
        }
        if (lastend < Math.PI * 2) {
            let startAngle = lastend;
            let endAngle = Math.PI * 2;
            let fillStyle = 'black';
            Pipe.foo2(startAngle, this.curent, endAngle, fillStyle, x, y, r, j, ctx);
        }
    }
}
Pipe.t = null;
// ---
let pipe = new Pipe(document.body);
```

Comment: ДА! как упрощённый вариант - считывать цвет под курсором

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]