# Выделение и удаление полигонов на canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть задача позволить пользователю выборочно выделять и удалять полигоны которые он рисует. Проблема 1: как выделить нужный полигон из возможного множества полигонов нарисованных пользователем. Проблема 2: как сделать чтобы когда нужно выделить полигон при клике на полигон не оставалась точка координат и не добавлялись данные в массив с координатами. Проблема 3: при выделении полигона это должно быть видно(изменение strokestyle или fillstyle).
Пожалуйста объясните как реализовать задуманное, предложите варианты. Спасибо!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Streaming</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

    <p style="color: #dddddd; margin-left:30px;">
            X:<span id="offsetX"></span>
            Y:<span id="offsetY"></span>
    </p>

<div class="main_cont">

    <canvas id='canvas' height='500' width='500' style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas>
    <dialog id='dialog'>
            <p id='p_dialog'></p>
            <button id="closeWindow">Закрыть</button>
    </dialog>

    <div id="button_container">

        <button id = "clearCanvas">Clear canvas</button>
        <button id="showCoord">Show coord</button>
        <button id = "clearSaveCoord">Clear save coord</button>
        <button id = "repainButton">Load</button>
        <button id = "saveCoord">Save</button>
        <button id = "back">Back one point</button>
        <button id = "readCoord">Read Coord</button>

        <form action="" method="post" target="_blank">
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" id="rect_coord" name="coordinates" required><br>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="button2" style='margin-top:20px;' type="submit" name="Save"  title="">
        </p>

        </form>


    </div>

    <dialog id='dialogRedCoord'>
        <div id="add" style="display:grid;">
            <button id="addInput">&#43;</button>
        </div>
        <button id="closeWindowReadCoord">Закрыть</button>
        <button id="addDataFromInput">Пременить</button>
    </dialog>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    //======================================================================================================
    let can = document.getElementById('canvas');// холст
    can.width          = 500;                   // ширина холста
    can.height         = 500;                   // высота холста
    let ctx            = can.getContext('2d');  // выбрать пространство
    let pts            = [[]];                  // массив с точками координат
    let data           = null;                  // массив координат из localStorage
    let clearCoordinat;                         // сохраненые данные в localStorage
    let x, y;
    //======================================================================================================
    // выводим отображение координат(offset) на холсте при ведении мыши
    document.getElementById('canvas').onmousemove = function(event){
        event = event || window.event;
        document.getElementById('offsetX').innerHTML = event.offsetX;
        document.getElementById('offsetY').innerHTML = event.offsetY;
    };

    //======================================================================================================
    // убирает выделение холста синим цветом при двойном нажатии мыши
    document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.onselectstart = function () { return false; };

    //======================================================================================================
    // отрисовывает сохраненные координаты фигур
    document.getElementById('repainButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('storeObj'));
        // извлекаем данные из localstorege
        if (data === null){
            return alert('Нет сохраненых объектов');
        } else{
        console.info('ЭТО data', data)
        pts = data       // новая коллекция точек /// я изменил одну эту строчку
        repaintButton(); // вызываев функцию для отрисовки с кнопки
              }

        document.getElementById('clearCanvas').addEventListener('click', function() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
        });
    },false);

    //=======================================================================================================
    // шаг назад по нажатию кнопки при раставлении точек
    document.getElementById('back').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        pts[pts.length-1].pop()
        repaint();
    },false);

    //======================================================================================================
    // замыкаение и отрисовка фигуры по двойному клику вызовом func(repaint) (JQUERY)
    $( "#canvas" ).dblclick(function() {
        pts[pts.length-1].pop(); // удалим повторную точку
        pts.push([])             // новая коллекция точек
        repaint();               // вызываем функцию отрисовки

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // сохранение фигур в localStorage
        clearCoordinat = pts;
        document.getElementById('saveCoord').onclick = function(event) {
            if (clearCoordinat === null){
                alert('Нет данных для сохранения')
            } else {
                window.localStorage.setItem('storeObj', JSON.stringify(clearCoordinat));
                alert('Сохранено')
                   };
        };
    });

    //========================================================================================================
    // обработка массива с сохранеными точками в localStorage для отображения координат
    document.getElementById('showCoord').onclick = function(event) {
        let showCoord = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('storeObj'))

        if(showCoord !== null){
        let prop = Object.values(showCoord)

        for (let i in prop){
            for (let j in prop[i]){
                for(let v in prop[i][j]){
                    if(v%2==0){
                        prop[i][j][v] = ' x: ' + prop[i][j][v]
                    } else {
                        prop[i][j][v] = ' y: ' + prop[i][j][v]
                           };
                    };
                };
            };

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // делаем из масива словарь в формате json и придаем красивый вид
        showCoord = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, showCoord), null, 4)
        console.info(showCoord)

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // вывод обработаных данных в сплывающее окно
        document.getElementById('p_dialog').innerText = 'Координаты: ' + showCoord // заполнение координатами

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // всплывающее окно с сохраненными координатами
        let dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
        dialog.show();
        document.querySelector('#closeWindow').onclick = function() {
        dialog.close();
        };
        } else{
            alert('Нет сохраненых координат для отображения')
              };
    };

    //=========================================================================================================
        // отчистка поля input с кнопки  и удаление сохраненых координат из localStorage
        document.getElementById('clearSaveCoord').onclick = function(event) {
            if (clearCoordinat !== null){
                let delCoord = confirm("Вы уверены что хотите отчистить все? Это также приведет к удалению сохраненых координат.");
                    if (delCoord){
                    dialog.close();
                    document.getElementById("rect_coord").value = null;
                    window.localStorage.removeItem('storeObj');
                    return clearCoordinat = null;
          };
        }  else {
            alert('Нет сохраненных данных для удаления')
               };
    };
    //=======================================================================================================
    // события нажатия мыши и добавления координат в массив
    can.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
        pts[pts.length-1].push([
            e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft,
            e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop
        ]);
        repaint();
        [e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft, e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop]

    });

    //=======================================================================================================
    // функция рисования и обновления точек на холсте по точкам из массива pts
    function repaint(){

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height)

        ctx.strokeStyle = '#00f';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 253, 0.5)' // Цвет
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;                         // Толщина линий
        ctx.lineJoin = "miter";                    // Закругленность соединений линий

        // ***рисуем фигуры***
        // shape = фигура
        // j     = номер фигуры
        // p     = точка. выражена как значение двух координат x, y в массиве по 2 элемента
        // i     = index массива
        pts.forEach((shape, j)=> {
            ctx.beginPath();
            shape.forEach((p, i) => {
                ctx[i ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](...p);
            })

            if(j !== pts.length-1){
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            }

        ctx.stroke();
        })

        // рисуем синие точки только для последней фигуры
        pts[pts.length-1].forEach((p, i) => {
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 253, 0.5)'
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(...p, 3.6 / 1.4 ,0, Math.PI * 2); //Круг
            // ctx.rect(...p, 6, 6)
            ctx.stroke();

        })

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // кнопка очистки canvas
        document.getElementById('clearCanvas').addEventListener('click', function() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

            return pts = [[]];// отчищаю массив с точками для отрисовки фигуры
        }, false)
    };

    //======================================================================================================
    // функция асинхронный запрос к локальному файлу на сервере coord.json
    function readTextFile(path_to_file, callback) {
        let rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        rawFile.open("GET", path_to_file, true);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
                callback(rawFile.responseText);
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    };

    //=======================================================================================================
    // получаем фаил
    readTextFile("http://localhost:5000/static/json/coord.json", function(text){
        let file_data = JSON.parse(text);
    });

    //======================================================================================================
    // функция для отрисовки из сохраненых координат в localStorage
    function repaintButton(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height);

        ctx.strokeStyle = '#00f';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 253, 0.5)' // Цвет
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;                         // Толщина линий
        ctx.lineJoin = "miter";                    // Закругленность соединений линий

        // рисуем фигуры
        data.forEach((shape, j) => {
            ctx.beginPath();
            shape.forEach((p, i) => {
                ctx[i ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](...p);

            })
            if(j !== data.length-1){
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
            ctx.stroke();
        })

        // рисуем синие точки только для последней фигуры
        data[data.length-1].forEach((p, i) => {
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(...p, 10 / 20 ,0, Math.PI * 2); //Круг
            ctx.stroke();

        })
    };

    //======================================================================================================
    // создаю всплывающее окно с динамическим добавлением элементов input для ввода координат
    document.getElementById('readCoord').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        let dialogReadCoord = document.getElementById('dialogRedCoord');
        dialogReadCoord.show();
        addElementInput
        document.querySelector('#closeWindowReadCoord').onclick = function() {
        dialogReadCoord.close();
        };
    });

    //=====================================================================================================
    // функция динамического создания, добавления в DOM и удаления элементов input (JQUERY)
        let addElementInput = $(document).ready(function () {
        let max_fields   = 1000;
        let wrapper      = $("#add");
        let add_button   = $("#addInput");

        let x = 1;
        $(add_button).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){
                x++;
                $(wrapper).append('<div><span>X:</span><input class="input_coord" type="" name=""><span>Y:</span><input class="input_coord" type="" name=""><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>'); //add input box
            } else{
                  alert('You Reached the limits')
                  }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });

    //=====================================================================================================
    document.getElementById('addDataFromInput').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let coordFromInput = [[]];
    let text = document.getElementsByClassName("input_coord");

    coordFromInput = coordFromInput.push(text);
    console.log(typeof coordFromInput);
});

    //======================================================================================================
    // pts = this.pts;
    // функция отслеживания состояния canvas



let mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
    };

let selected = false;





let Poligon = function(...points) {
  this.points = pts
}

Poligon.prototype = {
  draw() {
    this.points.forEach((shape, j)=> {
            ctx.beginPath();
            shape.forEach((p, i) => {
                ctx[i ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](...p);
            })

            if(j !== this.points.length-1){
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            }

        ctx.stroke();
        })
  },
  mouseIn() {
    return PointInPoligon(mouse, ...this.points)
  }
};



let shapes = [
  new Poligon(
    pts.forEach((shape, j)=> {
            ctx.beginPath();
            shape.forEach((p, i) => {
                ctx[i ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](...p);
            })

            if(j !== pts.length-1){
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            }

        ctx.stroke();
        })
  ),

]

shapes.forEach(n => n.draw())

window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  mouse.x = e.pageX - can.offsetLeft;
  mouse.y = e.pageY - can.offsetTop;

  if (selected) {
    selected.points.forEach(n => {
      n.x += e.movementX
      n.y += e.movementY
    })

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height)
    shapes.forEach(n => n.draw())
  }
};

window.onmousedown = function() {
  if (!selected) {
    shapes.forEach(n => {
      if (n.mouseIn(mouse)) {
        selected = n
      }
    })
  }
};

window.onmouseup = function() {
  selected = null;
};





function PointInPoligon(points) {
    return this.points
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/988105/188366

Comment: @Stranger in the Q доброе утро! Объясните пожалуйста: 1 мне нужно создать дополнительный конвас один для моих фигур которые будет рисовать пользователь , а второй для копий этих фигур помеченных цветом? 2 я вижу вычисления в формулах где есть ширина и высота, у меня как таковой ширины и высоты нет , пользователь может нарисовать прямые линии из двух точек , как мне с этим быть?

Comment: Доброе, Вам точно svg не подходит?

Comment: Уже слишком много сделал на конвасе, возможно было бы проще на svg. Вы же видели мой проект на svg его сложно переделать будет? еще этот момент не изучал, вообще мне нужно в итоге сделать эти полигоны редактируемыми , что бы онлайн пользователь мог их изменять менять точки , расширять границы , удалять. Подскажите как мне поступить может действительно переделать проект на svg , но главное условие без доп библиотек макс это JQuery. Вы не подскажите где я более подробно могу ознакомится с различного рода формулами для работы с конвасом и svg?

Comment: формулы это из школьного курса математики, у меня там ширина и высота потому что я квадраты рисую, для этого примера это не важно. на svg было бы проще - нет нужды много делать вручную, в том числе морочиться с ховером И так далее. еще наведение можно определять математически.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q вот вы профессиональным взглядом смотрите, много изменений придется внести в проект ? или это полностью его переделывать ? мне нужно это понять я с svg вообще не работал не разу.

Comment: про ширину и высоту я понял , что вы квадраты рисуете, а как мне учесть, что полигон может быть абсолютно любой фигурой?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98651/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-hiddenfox29).