# Как проверить соответствуют ли координаты мышки фигуре на экране?

Tags: алгоритм

Допустим есть на экране фигура треугольник. Как создать условие проверки попадания координат мышки в этот треугольник?

Comment: если фигур не много, то можно математически, однако, есть варианты https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/988105/188366

Answer (score 0):

Реализация - считаются произведения (1, 2, 3 - вершины треугольника, 0 - точка):

(x1 - x0) * (y2 - y1) - (x2 - x1) * (y1 - y0)

(x2 - x0) * (y3 - y2) - (x3 - x2) * (y2 - y0)

(x3 - x0) * (y1 - y3) - (x1 - x3) * (y3 - y0)

Если они одинакового знака, то точка внутри треугольника, если что-то из этого - ноль, то точка лежит на стороне, иначе точка вне треугольника.

[источник](http://www.cyberforum.ru/algorithms/thread144722.html)