# canvas Как отследить на какой квадрат на холсте нажали?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отследить на какой из квадратов созданных в холсте было нажато ? Вот пример

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasGame");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var currentHeight = window.innerHeight / 2;
canvas.height = currentHeight;
canvas.width = currentHeight;


var btnSize = currentHeight / 3;

function createRect(recX, recY) {
  var path = new Path2D();
  path.rect(recX, recY, btnSize, btnSize);
  path.closePath();
  colorizeRect(path);
}

createRect(0, 0); /// 1
createRect(btnSize, 0); /// 2
createRect(btnSize * 2, 0); // 3

createRect(0, btnSize); //4
createRect(btnSize, btnSize); /// 5
createRect(btnSize * 2, btnSize); // 6

createRect(0, btnSize * 2); //7
createRect(btnSize, btnSize * 2); // 8
createRect(btnSize * 2, btnSize * 2); // 9


function colorizeRect(path) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
  // ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(225,225,225,0.5)";
  ctx.fill(path);
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
  ctx.stroke(path);
}

function getXY(canvas, event) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const XY = getXY(canvas, e);
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(path, XY.x, XY.y)) { /// How get path of rect ?
    // Do Something with the click
    alert("clicked in rectangle")
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#canvasGame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasGame"></canvas>
```

Как правильно передать path квадрата?
Как получить порядковый номер созданного квадрата в холсте по нажатию на его область допустим в alert() и поменять ему цвет?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/987993/%d0%90%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-canvas-%d0%b8-hover-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasGame");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var currentHeight = window.innerHeight / 2;
canvas.height = currentHeight;
canvas.width = currentHeight;

let pathArr = []; //Создаём массив, в котором будем хранить все пути

var btnSize = currentHeight / 3;

function createRect(recX, recY) {
  var path = new Path2D();
  path.rect(recX, recY, btnSize, btnSize);
  path.closePath();
  colorizeRect(path);
  pathArr.push(path);
}

createRect(0, 0); /// 1
createRect(btnSize, 0); /// 2
createRect(btnSize * 2, 0); // 3

createRect(0, btnSize); //4
createRect(btnSize, btnSize); /// 5
createRect(btnSize * 2, btnSize); // 6

createRect(0, btnSize * 2); //7
createRect(btnSize, btnSize * 2); // 8
createRect(btnSize * 2, btnSize * 2); // 9

function colorizeRect(path, paint = false) {
  (!paint) ? ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF": ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(225,225,225,0.5)";

  ctx.fill(path);
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
  ctx.stroke(path);
}



function getXY(canvas, event) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const XY = getXY(canvas, e);

  //Делаем проверку подошёл ли хоть 1 путь из массива
  pathArr.forEach(i => {
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(i, XY.x, XY.y)) {
      colorizeRect(i, true);
      alert("clicked in rectangle")
    }
  });
}, false);
```

```css
#canvasGame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasGame"></canvas>
```