# Как менять картинку при наведении на Сanvas?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

Есть у меня скрипт, который меняет картинку при наведении на нее. А как мне это сделать на Canvas?

```js
function onHover()
{
    $("#menuImg").attr('src', 'https://sun9-51.userapi.com/c205520/v205520651/442fb/m925WBRlXR8.jpg?ava=1');
}

function offHover()
{
    $("#menuImg").attr('src', 'https://pp.userapi.com/c841624/v841624151/5a335/PkaZQTScko0.jpg?ava=1');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" >  
  <a href="#" id="home">
    <img id="menuImg" src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841624/v841624151/5a335/PkaZQTScko0.jpg?ava=1" alt="logo" onmouseover="onHover();" 
      onmouseout="offHover();" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Адаптивный Canvas и hover на объекте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/987993/%d0%90%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-canvas-%d0%b8-hover-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть так?

```js
function imgChange(imagePath) {
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  };
  img.src = imagePath;
}
```

```html
<body onload="imgChange('https://sun9-51.userapi.com/c205520/v205520651/442fb/m925WBRlXR8.jpg?ava=1')">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" onmouseover="imgChange('https://pp.userapi.com/c841624/v841624151/5a335/PkaZQTScko0.jpg?ava=1')" onmouseout="imgChange('https://sun9-51.userapi.com/c205520/v205520651/442fb/m925WBRlXR8.jpg?ava=1')"></canvas>
```