# Canvas нанести текст на изображение, чтобы текст был частью изображения

Tags: javascript, canvas, typescript, html5-canvas

Делаю игру papers, please в браузере.

Сейчас реализовано:

- Есть стол, на нем документы, которые можно перетаскивать (пока перетаскиваю цветные прямоугольники)
- Есть данные документов (имя, фамилия, возраст, пол, номер паспорта и тд...)
- Есть шаблон документа, в котором есть поля под текст

> Нужно вставить в этот шаблон документа данные, чтобы потом при
> перетаскивании документа, текст оставался на своих местах

Должно получится что-то вроде этого:

[image]

Вот ВЕСЬ код класса, который реализует отрисовку документов (пока прямоугольники)
Использую TS

```js
class RenderDesk {
    // Размеры окна документа
    private w: number = window.innerWidth; // ширина всего стола
    private h: number; // высота всего стола
    // Canvas
    private canvasDesk: HTMLCanvasElement; // элемент canvas стола
    private canvasPapers: HTMLCanvasElement; // элемент canvas документов
    private deskCtx: CanvasRenderingContext2D; // контекст самого стола
    private papersCtx: CanvasRenderingContext2D; // контекст канваса с документами
    private pixel: number; // размер игрового пикселя

    // Размеры столов (сам стол, окошко с посетителями, стол для сдачи документов)
    private deskWidth_w: number; // ширина оновного стола
    private deskWidth_h: number; // ширина оновного стола
    private visitWindow_w: number;
    private visitWindow_h: number;
    private miniDesk_w: number;
    private miniDesk_h: number;

    // Перетаскивание
    private docCoords: { [key: string]: IPaperCoords } = {};
    private lastIndex: number = 0;
    private mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    private selected: IPaperCoords | boolean = false;

    // Если true, то разрешаем отдать документы
    public checked: boolean;

    constructor () {
        // Размер одного игрового пикселя
        this.pixel = Math.round(this.w / 512);
        // Высота всего стола
        this.h = window.innerHeight - this.pixel * 70;

        // canvas
        this.canvasDesk = document.querySelector("#desk");
        this.canvasPapers = document.querySelector("#papers");

        // Контекст
        this.deskCtx = this.canvasDesk.getContext("2d");
        this.papersCtx = this.canvasPapers.getContext("2d");

        // Размеры
        this.canvasDesk.width = this.canvasPapers.width = this.w;
        this.canvasDesk.height = this.canvasPapers.height = this.h;

        // -----------Задаем размеры "окон"-------------//
        // Основной стол
        this.deskWidth_w = this.w / 3 * 2; // ширина основного стола (2/3 от всего стола)
        this.deskWidth_h = this.h; // высота основного стола (во всю высоту)

        // Окно для посетителей
        this.visitWindow_w = this.w / 3 * 1; // ширина окна для посетителей (1/3 от всей ширины стола)
        this.visitWindow_h = this.h / 2; // высота окна для посетителей (половина высоты)

        // Мини столик для сдачи документов
        this.miniDesk_w = this.w / 3 * 1; // ширина мини столика (1/3 от всей ширины стола)
        this.miniDesk_h = this.h / 2; // высота мини столика (половина высоты)

        // Документы еще не проверены
        this.checked = false;

        // ----------------- События для перетаскивания документов ----------------- //
        this.canvasPapers.onmousemove = e => {
            // при движении сохраняем координаты мыши
            this.mouse.x = e.pageX;
            this.mouse.y = e.pageY - (window.innerHeight - this.canvasPapers.height); // тк нужно координаты относительно canvas
        };

        let isCursorInRect = (paper: IPaperCoords): boolean => {
            let mouse = this.mouse;

            // Проверяем входят ли координаты мыши в диапазон точек документа
            return (
                mouse.x > paper.x &&
                mouse.x < paper.x + paper.w &&
                mouse.y > paper.y &&
                mouse.y < paper.y + paper.h
            );
        };

        let zIndexChange = (zIndex: number) => {
            // Если zIndex выбранного документа самый большой, то он лежит выше всех, поднимать его вверх не надо
            if (zIndex == this.lastIndex) return;
            else {
                // Перебираем все документы
                for (let paperName in this.docCoords) {
                    // Текущий перебираемый документ
                    let paper = this.docCoords[paperName];

                    // Если документы лежат ниже всплывающего документа, то их порядок не меняется
                    if (paper.zIndex < zIndex) continue;
                    else if (paper.zIndex == zIndex)
                        // Если zIndex документа равен zIndex перетаскиваемого документа, то он должен всплыть наверх
                        paper.zIndex = this.lastIndex; // zIndex максимальный
                    else
                        // Чтобы очистить максимальный zIndex для всплывающего документа,
                        // смещаем zIndex всех выше лежащих документов на одну единицу вниз
                        paper.zIndex--;
                }
            }
        };

        window.onmousedown = () => {
            // При зажатии клавиши определяем находится ли какой-то документ под координатами мыши
            if (!this.selected /*если какой-то элемент выбран - значит он перетаскивается*/) {
                // Перебираем все документы, которые лежат на столе
                Object.values(this.docCoords)
                    // Сортируем их по уменьшению zIndex
                    .sort((a, b) => (a.zIndex < b.zIndex ? 1 : a.zIndex == b.zIndex ? 0 : -1))
                    .every(paper => {
                        // Если курсор на документе с самым большим zIndex, то перетаскиваем его
                        if (isCursorInRect(paper)) {
                            this.selected = paper;
                            zIndexChange(paper.zIndex);
                            return false;
                        } else
                            // Берем документ с меньшим zIndex
                            return true;
                    });
            }
        };

        window.onmouseup = () => {
            // Отпустили мышь - ничего не выбрано
            this.selected = false;
        };
    }

    public render () {
        // Сокращение
        let ctx = this.deskCtx;

        // Отрисовываем окно для посетителей
        ctx.fillStyle = "aqua";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.visitWindow_w, this.visitWindow_h);

        // Отрисовываем мини столик для сдачи документов
        ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
        ctx.fillRect(0, this.visitWindow_h, this.miniDesk_w, this.miniDesk_h);

        // Отрисовываем основной стол для документов
        ctx.fillStyle = "brown";
        ctx.fillRect(this.visitWindow_w, 0, this.deskWidth_w, this.deskWidth_h);
    }

    public submitDocs (
        passpor: Passport,
        entryPermit: EntryPermit,
        personalCard: PersonalCard
    ): Promise<boolean> {
        let ctx = this.papersCtx;
        let docH = 100;
        let docW = 60;

        // Размеры пасспорта
        this.docCoords.passport = {
            x: this.miniDesk_w / 2,
            y: this.canvasDesk.height - this.miniDesk_h,
            w: docW,
            h: docH,
            color: "red",
            zIndex: 2,
            giveAnimation: false,
            visible: true
        };

        // Размеры личной карты
        this.docCoords.personalCard = {
            x: this.miniDesk_w / 2,
            y: this.canvasDesk.height - this.miniDesk_h,
            w: 70,
            h: 35,
            color: "magenta",
            zIndex: 0,
            giveAnimation: false,
            visible: true
        };

        // Размеры рвзрешения на въезд
        this.docCoords.entryPermit = {
            x: this.miniDesk_w / 2,
            y: this.canvasDesk.height - this.miniDesk_h,
            w: 90,
            h: 150,
            color: "white",
            zIndex: 1,
            giveAnimation: false,
            visible: true
        };

        // Размеры рвзрешения на въезд
        this.docCoords.entryPermit2 = {
            x: this.miniDesk_w / 2,
            y: this.canvasDesk.height - this.miniDesk_h,
            w: 90,
            h: 150,
            color: "black",
            zIndex: 3,
            giveAnimation: false,
            visible: true
        };

        // Записываем в lastIndex самый высокий zIndex
        this.lastIndex = Object.values(this.docCoords).length - 1;

        // Создаем промис
        let verification: Promise<boolean> = new Promise(resolve => {
            // 60 раз в секунду перерисовываем документы
            let papersFrame = setInterval(() => {
                // Очищаем холст
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasPapers.width, this.canvasPapers.height);

                // Перебираем все документы, которые лежат на столе
                Object.values(this.docCoords)
                    // Сортируем их по возрастанию zIndex
                    .sort((a, b) => (a.zIndex > b.zIndex ? 1 : a.zIndex == b.zIndex ? 0 : -1))
                    .forEach(paper => {
                        // Если документ отдали, то его отрисовывать не надо
                        if (!paper.visible) return;

                        // Цвет отриосвываемого документа
                        ctx.fillStyle = paper.color;

                        // Определяем позицию документа (на мини столе, в окне для посетителей, на основном столе)
                        if (paper.x + paper.w / 2 < this.miniDesk_w) {
                            // Документ лежит на маленьком столе или в окне для посетителей
                            ctx.fillRect(paper.x, paper.y, paper.w, paper.h);

                            // Документ находится в окне для посетителей и человек отпустил документ
                            if (paper.y + paper.h + 10 < this.visitWindow_h && !this.selected)
                                // Запускаем анимацию
                                paper.giveAnimation = true;

                            // Анимация (отдаем документ посетителю) если он проверин checked
                            if (paper.giveAnimation && this.checked) {
                                // Если низ документа еще не дошел до края окна, просто двигаем документ
                                if (paper.y + paper.h < this.visitWindow_h) paper.y += 20;
                                else {
                                    // Иначе двигаем и уменьшаем высоту документа, чтобы он "скрылся" из вида
                                    paper.y += 20;
                                    paper.h -= 20;

                                    // Если документ скрылся, перестаем его анимировать и запрещаем отрисовываться
                                    if (paper.y >= this.visitWindow_h) {
                                        paper.giveAnimation = false;
                                        paper.visible = false;

                                        // Проверяем все ли документы сдали
                                        let end_of_verificate = Object.values(this.docCoords).every(
                                            // Если документ сдан, то он невидимый (visible = false)
                                            paper => !paper.visible
                                        );

                                        // Если все документы сдали, то завершаем промис
                                        if (end_of_verificate) {
                                            resolve(true);
                                            clearInterval(papersFrame);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if (paper.giveAnimation) {
                                console.log(234);
                                // Если документы не проверены, но их пытаются отдать
                                if (paper.y < this.canvasDesk.height - this.miniDesk_h)
                                    paper.y += 20;
                                else paper.giveAnimation = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Документ лежит на основном столе
                            ctx.fillRect(paper.x, paper.y, paper.w * 2, paper.h * 2);
                        }
                    });

                // Если какой-то документ перетаскивается, то изменяем его координаты на координаты мыши
                if (this.selected) {
                    (this.selected as IPaperCoords).x =
                        this.mouse.x - (this.selected as IPaperCoords).w / 2;
                    (this.selected as IPaperCoords).y =
                        this.mouse.y - (this.selected as IPaperCoords).h / 2;
                }
            }, 1000 / 60);
        });

        return verification;
    }
}
```

Comment: ТО ли я не совсем понял, то ли вы. Нужно, чтобы потом текст перетягивался вместе с документом, на который он наложен. И через input так точно в поле и не попадешь(

Comment: Зачем мне какие-то инпуты, если у меня данные есть в виде объекта? Их я в любой момент могу вставить на холст. Вопрос в том как вставить так, чтобы потом перетаскивать?

Comment: ясно, я не так вопрос понял. Рисуйте текст относительно местоположения карточки, а не всего холста.

Comment: ну а как я его передвигать буду?!

Comment: Начинали со "вставить текст в изображение" - закончили - "как я его передвигать буду" . https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/987993/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-canvas-%D0%B8-hover-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5#answer-988105 - вот здесь реализован drag&drop объектов на canvas

Comment: У меня уже реализован drag and drop! Мне нужно в эти прямоугольники вставить текст, чтобы когда я drag and drop эти прямоугольники, текст двигался вместе с ними, понятно?

Comment: Зачем передвигать отдельно текст? Если текст нарисован относительно местоположения карточки, то передвигая карточку, будет передвигаться и текст. Понятно?

Comment: аа, кажется понятно. Рисую документ, на его координатах рисую текст, изменяю координаты документа, изменяются текста. НЕ сразу понял, тк у меня в голове была одна мысль - нарисовать текст на документе и "объединить" их в одну картинку, но на js вроде как нельзя. Спасибо

Comment: @Дмытрык не понятно. Каким образом текст будет сам передвигаться за карточкой? Или речь идёт не про канвас?

Comment: У меня координаты документа, относительно них координаты текста. 60 раз в секунду отрисовываю это. При перемещении отслеживаю координаты мыши, меняю координаты документа. Вообщем я понял

Comment: @ᅠhᅠ, `Если текст нарисован относительно местоположения карточки, то передвигая карточку, будет передвигаться и текст` - имеено так, как Вы и сделали в своем ответе

Comment: @Дмытрык ну просто я бы не понял если бы спрашивал ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
const w = canvas.width = innerWidth
const h = canvas.height = innerHeight

const passport = {
  w: 140,
  h: 200,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  bg: 'tomato',
  info: {
    name: ['heh', 10, 30],
  }
}

update()

function rectPointCollision(point, rect) {
  return point.x > rect.x && point.x < rect.x + rect.w && point.y > rect.y && point.y < rect.y + rect.h
}

document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  drag(e, passport)
})

function drag(e, element) {
  if (!rectPointCollision({
      x: e.x,
      y: e.y
    }, element)) return

  sx = e.x - element.x
  sy = e.y - element.y

  document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', move)
  document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', stop)

  function move(e) {
    element.x = e.x - sx
    element.y = e.y - sy
  }

  function stop(e) {
    document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', move)
    document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', stop)
  }
}

function drawPassport() {
  context.fillStyle = passport.bg
  context.fillRect(passport.x, passport.y, passport.w, passport.h)
  context.fillStyle = 'white'
  context.font = '20px sans-serif'
  context.fillText(
    passport.info.name[0],
    passport.x + passport.info.name[1],
    passport.y + passport.info.name[2]
  )
}

function update() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)
  drawPassport()
  requestAnimationFrame(update)
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
```