# Как отобразить текст при наведении на область, canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Нужно при наведении на соответствующий квадрат отобразить название цвета в рамке (аналог атрибута title в HTML).

Ниже привел код который пока удалось создать:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(15, 15, 20, 20);
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(45, 15, 20, 20);
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(75, 15, 20, 20);

document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('mousemove', e=>{
  x = e.offsetX; // получаем позицию мыши по координате x
  y = e.offsetY; // получаем позицию мыши по координате y
  ctx.fillStyle = "#333";
  ctx.font = "bold 16px Arial";
  ctx.fillText("Красный", 20, 45);
  ctx.fillText("Синий", 50, 45);
  ctx.fillText("Зеленый", 80, 45);
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="110" height="50"></canvas>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/988105/188366

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно запомнить размеры и координаты квадратов и при движении мыши проверять каждый квадрат на коллизию с координатами курсора.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
const rs = [
  [15, 15, 20, 20, 'red'],
  [45, 15, 20, 20, 'blue'],
  [75, 15, 20, 20, 'green']
]

drawRect(rs[0]); drawRect(rs[1]); drawRect(rs[2])

function drawRect(r) {
  ctx.fillStyle = r[4]
  ctx.fillRect(...r.slice(0, 4))
}

function drawText(r) {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333'
  ctx.font = 'bold 16px Arial'
  const w = ctx.measureText(r[4]).width
  ctx.fillText(r[4], r[0] + r[3]/2 - w/2, 47)
}

function rectPointCollision(point, rect) {
  return (
    point[0] > rect[0] && point[0] < rect[0] + rect[2] &&
    point[1] > rect[1] && point[1] < rect[1] + rect[3]
  )
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  
  for (let r of rs) {
    drawRect(r)
    if (rectPointCollision([e.offsetX, e.offsetY], r))
      drawText(r)
  }
})
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="110" height="50"></canvas>
```