# Как нацепить эвент на объект класса

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как нацепить евент на объект класса?

***Листенер просто не видит картинку***

```
class test {
  constructor(x, y, w, h){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.image = null;
  }
  draw(){
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = '. . .';
        ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
    setPos(x,y){
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
    }
    attack(){
        this.image.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            console.log(1337);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Адаптивный Canvas и hover на объекте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/987993/%d0%90%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-canvas-%d0%b8-hover-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так не работает. Если вы рисуете Image на канве, вам нужно вешать обработчик на canvas. Затем получать координаты клика и в ручную проверять попали вы в image или нет. Лучше использовать какую нибудь библиотеку поверх канвы, типа PixiJS

Comment: https://codepen.io/Manfrid/pen/JjKaNNv?editors=0001 простой пример с кликом на канве